# Extending ArrayList and Creating new methods

Tags: java, arraylist, extend

I'm having a bit of a problem grasping something - I might be going about this completely wrong.

I am trying to create a class which extends ArrayList but has several methods which increase the functionality (at least for the program I am developing.)

One of the methods is a findById(int id), which searches each ArrayList object for a particular id match. So far it's working, but it won't let me do `for (Item i : this) { i.getId(); }`

I don't understand why?

Full code:

```
public class CustomArrayList<Item> extends ArrayList<Item> {

    // declare singleton instance
    protected static CustomArrayList instance;

    // private constructor
    private CustomArrayList(){
        // do nothing
    }

    // get instance of class - singleton
    public static CustomArrayList getInstance(){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new CustomArrayList();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Item findById(int id){
        Item item = null;
        for (Item i : this) {
            if (i.getId() == id) {
                      // something
         }
        }
        return item;
    }
    public void printList(){
        String print = "";
        for (Item i : this) {
            print += i.toString() + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(print);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
public class CustomArrayList<Item> extends ArrayList<Item> {
```

to

```
public class CustomArrayList extends ArrayList<Item> {
```

---

I suspect `Item` is the name of the class that you want to store in the list. By adding `<Item>` after `CustomArrayList` you're introducing a *type parameter* which shadows this class.

---

*With* the `<Item>` parameter, your code is equal to

```
public class CustomArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    // ...
        for (T i : this) { i.getId(); }
    // ...
}
```

which obviously won't always work, as `T` may refer to any type.

Comment: Awesome. Is that just the proper syntax, or was I trying to do something else? Thank you so much! Quick reply.

Comment: That is probably the proper syntax for your scenario. Updated the answer to explain why.

Comment: Thank you! That explains it very well.

Comment: To add to this, if you want to support various element types with common super type `Item`, use `public class ItemArrayList<T extends Item> extends ArrayList<T> { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

What is `getId()`? Presumably it's a method in *some* class, but we don't know *which* class.

If you've actually got a class called `Item` with a `getId()` method, which this is meant to be a list of, you simply need to stop your class from being generic. So instead of this:

```
public class CustomArrayList<Item> extends ArrayList<Item> {
```

you want:

```
public class CustomArrayList extends ArrayList<Item> {
```

Currently within your class, `Item` doesn't refer to a class called Item, it refers to a *type parameter* called `Item`.

Now personally:

- I wouldn't avoid creating singletons unless you really have to
- If you have to, I'd avoid creating them in the way you have (which isn't thread-safe)
- I wouldn't extend `ArrayList<>` unless I really had to, preferring composition over inheritance

Comment: I'm creating a singleton for the reason that I can only have one. I know that the way I'm creating it isn't thread safe - I would need to have a "lock method", correct? What aioobe posted solved my problem, but I'm still interested in creating a thread-safe singleton.

Comment: The preferred way to create a singleton in Java 1.5+ is to use an Enum. See for instance this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/efficient-way-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-java