# Extending ArrayList<Type> in order to add custom filter function

Tags: java, android, oop, arraylist, extends

I have an `ArrayList<LineItem>` in an application. Each `LineItem` holds a line from a CSV file from another data source. LineItem is defined as follows:

```
  class LineItem {

    private Date date;
    private String clientname;
    private String action;

    LineItem(Date date, String clientname, String action) {
            this.Date = date;
            this.clientname = clientname;
            this.action = action;
    }
}
```

At current I'm loading as such:

```
ArrayList<LineItem> data;
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new File(data_file_name));
while (line = r.readLine() != false) {
  String[] elements = line.split(delimiter);
  data.add(new LineItem(elements[0], elements[1], elements[2]);
}
```

I'd like to extend ArrayList in order to create self referring filter functions such as `data.filter_by_client(clientName)` or `data.filter_by_daterange()`. I tried to create class `MyData extends ArrayList<LineItem>` however any of the filter functions I named are not recognized.

Is it possible to extend ArrayList<> and if so, how can I build public methods so that I can use them later in code such as

```
MyData data = new MyData(...);
MyData historic_activity_for_report = data.filter_by_single_date('3/14/2012');
```

**Background:** I'd like to take this external data file (imported on a regular basis from a central source as a CSV) of an employees' workday activity and allow a manager to get reports on an Android tablet.

Comment: What does android have to do with this?
Anyways, you should specify what you try to achieve: Calling these methods, do you want an iterator over the results? another arrayList just containing the results?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by filter? Is data.filter_by_single_date supposed to return a sub-array with only the LineItem's with that particular date?

Comment: It's an android application. While the crux is focused on how to accomplish this in Java itself.

Comment: Solace, yes, allow me to edit the main block of the question for more clarity.

Comment: I did some google foo and found a previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098615/extending-a-java-arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can extend ArrayList. What error are you getting? Just a suggestion. Have you looked at [Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained). You may not need to extend ArrayList. Guava is a good library to use.

Answer (score 0):

You're allowed to override the ArrayList class and implement your own methods such as .filter_by_single_date().

```
ArrayList<LineItem>data = new ArrayList<LineItem>(){

    public ArrayList<LineItem> filter_by_single_date(){

    }
};
```

But I don't really see any reason to do this. You can just make a method in your current class. The ArrayList is an instance var.